# Need Help Solving Question About Vectors in 3D Plane

Tags: vectors

Stuck on this question, would appreciate some help giving a direction for how to solve this.

ABCDA'B'C'D' is a cuboid. Input: AB = u, AD = v, AA' = w (u,v,w are vectors)

|u| = 1
|v| = sqrt(8)
|w| = sqrt(7)

X is a vertex on the plane BCC'B'

the angles between AX and the following vectors are all equal: AB, AC, AC'

The question wants me to represent AX using u,v,w

What I know is that I can use the formula cos(angle) = vec1*vec2 / |vec1||vec2| to get some relationship but this doesn't lead me to a solution, and I'm not sure how to use the input that X is placed on the BCC'B' plane...

Comment: relevant: image: http://i.imgur.com/WNMisoQ.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by writing $$\overrightarrow{AX}=\underline{u}+\lambda\underline{v}+\mu\underline{w}$$
From the given information, note that$$\underline{u}\cdot\underline{u}=1, \underline{v}\cdot\underline{v}=8,\underline{w}\cdot\underline{w}=7$$

Also, $$\underline{u}\cdot\underline{v}=\underline{v}\cdot\underline{w}=\underline{w}\cdot\underline{u}=0$$

Doing the scalar products, and taking the common angle to be $\theta$,

$$\overrightarrow{AX}\cdot\overrightarrow{AB}=1=|AX||AB|\cos\theta\Rightarrow|AX|\cos\theta=1$$
And
$$\overrightarrow{AX}\cdot\overrightarrow{AC}=1+8\lambda=|AX||AC|\cos\theta$$ but $$|AC|=\sqrt{1^2+8}=3\Rightarrow\lambda=\frac {1}{4}$$

Finally, $$\overrightarrow{AX}\cdot\overrightarrow{AC'}=1+8\lambda+7\mu=|AX||AC'|\cos\theta$$
But$$|AC|=\sqrt{1^2+8+7}=4\Rightarrow3+7\mu=4\Rightarrow\mu=\frac {1}{7}$$

Hence $$\overrightarrow{AX}=\underline{u}+\frac {1}{4}\underline{v}+\frac {1}{7}\underline{w}$$

Comment: CAUTION, it is $\overrightarrow{AX}\cdot\overrightarrow{AC}=1+\sqrt{8}\lambda=...$ instead of $\overrightarrow{AX}\cdot\overrightarrow{AC}=1+8\lambda=...$, the same for a $7$ which has to be replaced by a $\sqrt{7}$. The overall result I have found is that (your notations) $\lambda=1/\sqrt{2}$ and $\mu=1/\sqrt{7}$.

Comment: @JeanMarie...are you sure about that? I have edited my answer for a fuller explanation.

Comment: Yes, I am sure (unless I am completely tired ; it can happen): I agree for example with the correction $u.u=8$, but precisely, this makes $\|u\|=\sqrt{8}$

Comment: Thanks a lot! this was very useful. How can I mark as solved as guest?

Comment: I can rewrite the solution in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

$\vec{AX}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\y\\z \end{pmatrix}$ where $y$ and $z$ are unknowns.

$\vec{AB}=\begin{pmatrix}u\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix} \ \ $ $\vec{AC}=\begin{pmatrix}u\\v\\0 \end{pmatrix} \ \ $ $\vec{AC'}=\begin{pmatrix}u\\v\\w \end{pmatrix} \ \ $ with $u=1, v=\sqrt{8}, w=\sqrt{7}$.

$\vec{AB}, \vec{AC}, \vec{AC'}$ make the same angle $\alpha$ with $\vec{AX}$, thus :

$$\cos(\alpha)=\dfrac{\vec{AX}.\vec{AB}}{\| \vec{AX} \|\|\vec{AB}\|}=\dfrac{\vec{AX}.\vec{AC}}{\| \vec{AX} \|\|\vec{AC}\|}=\dfrac{\vec{AX}.\vec{AC'}}{\| \vec{AX} \|\|\vec{AC'}\|}$$

from which:

$$\dfrac{\vec{AX}.\vec{AB}}{\|\vec{AB}\|}=\dfrac{\vec{AX}.\vec{AC}}{\|\vec{AC}\|}=\dfrac{\vec{AX}.\vec{AC'}}{\|\vec{AC'}\|}$$

or

$$\dfrac{1}{1}=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{8}y}{3}=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{8}y+\sqrt{7}z}{4}$$

The solution of this system is: $y=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $z=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{7}}$.